# How to extraxt month from date

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get the month of today's date (e.g. 08):

```
set /a m=%date:~4,2% echo m
```

However, I get the error "Invalid number. constants are either decimal (17) hexadecimal(0x11), or octal(021)". Why? It was working fine until August.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dany Bee is correct - SET /A will attempt to treat 08 as octal and give that error message. You can get the value without the leading 0 by prefixing with a 1 and computing mod 100.

```
set /a "month=1%date:~4,2% %% 100"
```

Please be aware that parsing values from the `%date%` is locale dependent. On my machine I must use `set /a "month=1%date:~0,2% %% 100"`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the same thing to get the "day" but it did not work. Why? set /a d=%date:~7,2% %% 100

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
set "month=%date:~4,2%"
echo %month%
```

cmd assumes all numbers with leading zeros as octal numbers. "08" is not a valid octal number.